# How to define ContentMD5 parameter for AWS S3 PHP SDK 2 method call

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Maybe I'm missing something, but I've been looking everywhere and can't find a decent explanation for the ContentMD5 required parameter in the PHP SDK 2 for deleteObjects (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_deleteObjects)

Docs say it "defaults to true", however that makes me assume it's a boolean value - however, I'm always getting a 4** response when executing the command with a Boolean - I think it's something else.

It's a simple call:

```
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
'key' => S3_KEY,
'secret' => S3_SECRET
));

$response = $s3->deleteObjects(array(
'Bucket'    => $bucket,
'Objects'   => $array_of_keys,
'ContentMD5' => ???????????
));
```

Any help on how I define the ContentMD5 param would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage for the deleteObjects method in the AWS PHP SDK v2 is this one:

```
$s3->deleteObjects(array(
    'Bucket' => 'your-bucket-name',
    'Objects' => array(
        array('Key'=>'first-file.ext'),
        array('Key'=>'second-file.ext')
    )
);
```

You do not need to define the ContentMD5 parameter.

Comment: The docs say it's required?? Are the docs wrong? Strangely, the call without the ContentMD5 param goes through and returns the correct Guzzle model with the deleted keys, however, nothing gets deleted - files are still on S3.

Comment: By not specifying the value for ContentMD5, it will use the default value, and, as you mentioned, the call will go trough. You could also try to specify the keys with and without a leading / and see which one works (I've seen reports that one works while the other doesn't; It's normal for the deleteObjects call to return a successful status for keys that don't exist)

Comment: Wow. You're right. +1 for you, -1 for Amazon. Bad docs, wrong return messages.

Comment: Delete operations in S3 are [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). You can delete the same key over and over again and it will always be a success. This also means that if you try to delete an object that never existed, it is still considered a success, since if the item is not there, then it is effectively deleted. Since the DeleteObjects operation is a batch operation, it will return with a 200 response, even if there are some errors. The response structure in the API docs shows how to check the keys that were deleted and the ones that weren't.

Comment: The documentation about ContentMD5 is misleading though. I'll see what I can do about that. Also, feel free to open an issue on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php